# Blob detection on noisy, low resolution image with background in Matlab

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

I have this image showing some cells, which have to be detected for further analysis. Notice that it has a very low contrast.

[image: Original image]

I then adjust the contrast:

```
im_contrastadjusted = imadjust(im);
```

[image: Contrast adjusted]

Subtract the background:

```
background = imopen(im_contrastadjusted,strel('disk',3));
im_bgadjusted = im_contrastadjusted-background;
```

[image: Background subtracted]

Filter out the noise:

```
im_noisefiltered = medfilt2(im_bgadjusted);
```

[image: Filtered noise]

Adjust the contrast again:

```
im_contrastadjusted2 = imadjust(im_noisefiltered);
```

[image: Contrast adjusted again]

And then convert it to binary using a high threshold:

```
im_bw = im2bw(im_contrastadjusted2, 0.98);
```

[image: Converted to binary]

I overlayed the boundaries of the binary image on the original image:

[image: Overlayed]

This result is pretty decent, but clumps of cells often times gets recognized as one cell. I tried to do a watershed segmentation, but the image is too low resolution to get a good result. I could use some ideas to improve the result further.

Comment: Have you tied using edge detection? http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/edge.html